# Discord.js bot replies itself when awaiting messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

After the bot sends the message **message.channel.send('Fortnite added!');** or another roles, the bot replies to itself with the default message until the 5 seconds ran out.

```
const awaiting = await message.channel.send('Awaiting your role(s)...');

const roles = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => {
    console.log(msg.content);

    switch(msg.content) {
        case 'fortnite':
            message.member.addRole('ROLEID');
            message.channel.send('**Fortnite** added!')
            break;
        case 'pubg':
            message.member.addRole('ROLEID');
            message.channel.send('**PUBG** added!')
            break;
        case 'hots':
            message.member.addRole('ROLEID');
            message.channel.send('**HOTS** added!')
            break;
        default:
            message.channel.send('This is not a valid role!');
            return;
    };

}, {time: 5000});

message.channel.send('Await completed!')
```

**Node that I'm storing the command in a different file**

What I tried so far:

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

in my bot.js and the js file where this code comes from:

```
switch(msg.content.toLowerCase()) {}
```

trying to make it only work in lowercase.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: As i'm saying in the title, the bot is replying to itself when i add a role and send the message, my question is how i prevent the bot from doing that

Comment: "Discord.js bot replies itself when awaiting messages" that is not a question it is a statement.  Please update the post to explicitly ask your question.

Comment: What library are you using? the standard discord.js? nothing else? I ask because normally you listen for commands using [`client.on('message',..`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) - not `message.channel.awaitMessages(...`